# how to use jsoup to tidy up the html

Tags: jsoup

I am using jsoup and it is really nice to tidy up some html, but I have a piece of invalid html as following:

```
<p>The recurrence, in close succession <ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li></ul> second part of thisssss
```

What I want to get is :

```
<p>The recurrence, in close succession </p><ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li></ul> <p>second part of thisssss</p>
```

So is the jsoup capable of tidying up the html and return this output ?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

Yes, try this:

```
String html = "<p>The recurrence, in close succession <ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li></ul> second part of thisssss";
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

You can use another [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) as well.

Comment: Note that JSoup does actually clean up the HTML. It resolves issues like `<p><ol></ol></p>` and can be set to resolve e.g. `<br>`.